# Angular data table not refersh after adding some values to list

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Angular data table not refersh after adding some values to list

table

```
     <p-dataTable class="pc-datatable" [value]="dList[i].contactData" [responsive]="true">
```

ts file add

```
  let obj= new ContactData();
obj.conPerson = this.contactDialogForm.get("contPerson").value;
obj.conMode = this.contactDialogForm.get("contMode").value;
obj.conDetail = this.contactDialogForm.get("contDetail").value;
this.dList[this.selectedIndex].contactData.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
this.dList[this.selectedIndex].contactData = [...this.dList[this.selectedIndex].contactData, obj]
```

This might be happening because, `p-dataTable` does not get triggered after you update the array. In order to trigger, you need to create new array and put all data into that

Answer (score 0):

Because you push data to a list, but you do not change its `reference` and this change may not be `detachable` by angular. Even though it is a bad practice, this should solve your problem:

```
  let obj= new ContactData();
  obj.conPerson = this.contactDialogForm.get("contPerson").value;
  obj.conMode = this.contactDialogForm.get("contMode").value;
  obj.conDetail = this.contactDialogForm.get("contDetail").value;
  this.dList[this.selectedIndex].contactData.push(obj);
  // change reference by re-assignment
  this.dList[this.selectedIndex].contactData = [].concat(this.dList[this.selectedIndex].contactData);
```